My Tableview not updating on button click from .qml file
On button click i am calling updateEntries() function which I am expecting it should add rows into the model and show the tableview on the screen.But i am not seeing any table with data.
Also i have one observation if i give hardcoded values  m_list.size() > 0 ie. 1 or greater than 0 in XYZ::rowCount() function then on button click i am seeing table with data. why this happening could anyone explain me? I am using Tableview in .qml file.
Also my qml part is working fine.I also tested using Listmodel in qml.so it is showing table data.
so i hoping my qml code is working fine but having issue in model class.
int XYZ::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return m_list.size(); 
}

int XYZ::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return 1;
}


void XYZ::updateEntries() {

    QList<MyStruct> hardcodedEntries = {
        { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8" },
        { "10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60", "70", "80" }
    };

    // Clear existing data
    beginResetModel();
    m_list.clear();
    endResetModel();

    // Insert new rows
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), 0, hardcodedEntries.size() - 1);
    for (const MyStruct &entry : hardcodedEntries) {
        m_list.append(entry);
    }
    endInsertRows();

    emit dataChanged(index(0, 0), index(m_logEntries.size() - 1, columnCount() - 1));
}

QVariant XYZ::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid() || index.row() >= m_logEntries.size() || index.column() >= columnCount()) {
        return QVariant();
    }

    const MyStruct &entry = m_list.at(index.row());

    switch (role) {
    case Role1:
        return entry.parameter1;
    case Role2:
        return entry.parameter2;
    case Role3:
        return entry.parameter3;
    case Role4:
        return entry.parameter4;
    case Role5:
        return entry.parameter5;
    case Role6:
        return entry.parameter6;
    case Role7:
        return entry.parameter7;
    default:
        return QVariant();
    }
}

I am expecting that after clicking on 'ShowTable' button i should see table
because i am calling updateEntries() from .qml file.
Also i verified that rowCount() is increasing after adding rows but not seeing in table anything.

Please provide a comprehensive [mre], including the QML content and relative context creation.

your code explains nothing, please fix that. I see no QAbstractItemModel::roleNames() at least. Or just follow the example
